# Confusion about candlesticks colors

Tags: finance

[image]

Why is the second green candle stick green? Given that its closing price is less than the previous candlestick's closing price, shouldn't it be orange?

Source: coninbase 1m chart for ethereum: https://pro.coinbase.com/trade/ETH-GBP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a solid candlestick chart, a green candlestick means that the opening price for that period was lower than the closing price for that period. In other words, the price went up *during that time*.  So in your example, the price dropped from the close of the prior period, but rose back up slightly by the end of the period.

However, when a chart uses solid *and hollow* candlesticks, a hollow candlestick represents an upward movement over the period, and a green cnadlestick means that the price closed higher than the previous period's close. So a hollow green represents a period where the price rose but ended below the prior close.

Since all I see on coinbase are hollow green and solid red (or orange) candles, I suspect that they are just using hollow green candles to represent an upward move in that period and solid red to indicate a downward movement in that period, and not comparing to the prior ending price.

Comment: yup, I thought as much. Unless it's a bug with coinbase...(quite possible)